# How to change the text color of SlidingTabLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-actionbar-compat

I made an application which use the **ActionBarCompat**

I created the tabs using the **SlidingTabLayout** class.

the class is this:

[SlidingTabLayout.java](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)

***but I can not change the color of the tabs...***

my viewpager fragment is this:

```
<swmovil.fyb.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/mTabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

the application works great, but i can´t change the **color text** of the tabs...

I made the application after seeing the following example:

[rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ViewPager-ActionBarCompat](https://github.com/rudsonlive/Navigation-Drawer-ViewPager-ActionBarCompat)

How can i change the text color of the tabs text ?

thanks !!!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

1) First of all create color folder under res (/res/color)
2) create xml file selector.xml under /res/color folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:color="#504f4f" /> 
</selector>
```

3) Then in the populateTabStrip() method in SlidingTabLayout put this

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.selector));
```

now you have a selector and you can change the color of the text on any event you want

if that is not working add the following lines of code.
a) in populateTabStrip() method at the end add this

```
if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
    tabView.setSelected(true);
}
```

and b) change the onPageSelected() method to this

```
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            mTabStrip.getChildAt(i).setSelected(position == i);
        }
        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you help me changing the bacground color when clicked? Currently it shows the default holo blue.

Comment: @AtulOHolic i dont know how to to that. i am sorry

Comment: No issues. Thanks a lot for the above. Its a great help. :) Keep up the good work. :)

Comment: it wasn't working well for me till I realized that one needed to use the project's package and not the android one like so: tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(<your package name>.R.color.selector));

Comment: @AtulOHolic maybe you did not figured out how to set a background. At the same position in the code where you used the `setTextColor()` method you can call `tabTitleView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_tab));`

Comment: getColorStateList is deprecated. Use ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.selector);

Answer (score 15):

Open your file `SlidingTabLayout.java` (the default one from Google IO) and find the function `populateTabStrip()` , then after this code

```
mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
            tabView.setSelected(true);
        }
```

add the following line:

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(tabView.getContext(), R.color.grey);
tabTitleView.setTextColor(color);
```

Replace `R.color.grey` with your preferred color.

Comment: Yep. I think so, too.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to see the TextView the class is using.

```
tabTitleView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

In my class, the TextView was tabTitleView. If you are using the default example provided by Google, you will find it under populateTabStrip function.

Answer (score 4):

copy code of slidingtablayout and slidingtabstrip and put it in a java file.then make a customtab_title.xml in your layout folder and a selector.xml file in your drawable folder.
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:padding="10dp"
   >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:textColor="@drawable/slidingtab_title_color"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/unpressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/unpressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/unpressed" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
</selector>
```

And in your mainactivity or where u r showing your tabs add one line of code -  tabs.setCustomTabView(R.layout.customtab_title, R.id.textView2);

here tabs is slidingtablayout tabs;

to change indicator color add - 
 tabs.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.unpressed));

Comment: small comment, your textview doesn't have to be in a linearlayout.  it can be the only view in the xml.

Answer (score 2):

```
   @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {

  TextView tv = (TextView) mTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
 if (i==position)
  tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.white));
 else                             
  tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.tab_text_color));

        }
```

this may be help you

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this class doesn't support customizing the tab text color without editing  the code and always uses the default text color of the theme. You'll have to patch the class to allow setting the tabs text color by code or by style attribute.
One alternative is to use the [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) library.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for the SlidingTabLayout...You can set a custom tab view, which allows you to control the content of the tab and set a custom tab text color.  Have a look at slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId).

Answer (score 0):

I use Panayiotis Irakleous solution but I think it is better to avoid looping part in onPageSelected procedure.

The steps are the same, you need to add an int class member (example: `mCurrentTabIndex`) to save current tab index.

In steps 3.a, you need to add

```
mCurrentTabIndex = i;
```

So it will be like this:

```
if (i == mViewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
    tabView.setSelected(true);
    mCurrentTabIndex = i;
}
```

Last, in steps 3.b, replace the looping part to this:

```
mTabStrip.getChildAt(mCurrentTabIndex).setSelected(false);
mTabStrip.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);
mCurrentTabIndex = position;
```

So the code will be like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
        scrollToTab(position, 0);
    }

    mTabStrip.getChildAt(mCurrentTabIndex).setSelected(false);
    mTabStrip.getChildAt(position).setSelected(true);
    mCurrentTabIndex = position;

    if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
    }
}
```