# How to change text color in Sliding tabs

Tags: android, android-tabs, textcolor

I'm learning Android and don't understand how to change the color of the text in Sliding tabs of the Google Example SlidingTabs Colors:
https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/project.html

I tried to write:

```
<com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddffffff"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff">
```

But nothing happened.
Also text color didn't change when I used this :

```
@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title
```

in my Theme.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26955613/4713330

Answer (score 0):

There is whole library for page sliding tabs for colors.
You may wan to see this example.
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

There are many tutorial regarding changing color of page strip.