# How to change selected tab background colour in a swipeable tabs in android

Tags: android, colors, tabs

I am new bee to android using swipe able tabs in my application I was downloaded from [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) I want to change the back ground colour of the selected tab can any one help me how to do this in android.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955613/3276104) and use the methods in the library you downloaded or you can use the code from [Android example](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html)